# Can we disable aslr for linux kernel module (ko file)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Is there any way to disable ASLR for Linux kernel modules?

For example:

```
adb shell cat /proc/modules | grep module_name
module_name 8134656 27 - Live 0xffffffec11589000 (O)
```

Can we get the same address for all subsequent reboots?

Comment: There is a `nokaslr` kernel command line option. I do not think KASLR can be disabled for individual modules if the kernel booted with KASLR enabled.

Comment: Even without ASLR, the load address of a module is still likely to vary between boots, just based on which region of memory is available for loading it.  This has always been the case, long before there was any such thing as ASLR, and is why modules were designed as relocatable in the first place.  So I think you just need to design your module to be able to deal with being loaded at an arbitrary address, and then ASLR won't be a problem either.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible without disabling KASLR altogether. There is no special KASLR flag for modules, it's either enabled or disabled globally, modules included (as you can see [from the source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/arch/x86/kernel/module.c#L39)). If `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y` then the kernel image address as well as module addresses will be randomized, and this can be disabled only by using the `nokaslr` kernel command line parameter at boot.